# Why is Knockout.js not bindng

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to learn knockOut.js and can't really get off the ground.  When I call ko.applyBindings, my model is always undefined.

I've tried the solution already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672732/knockout-js-noob-looking-for-some-understanding-on-tutorial-1).

I have also tried in jsFiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4748N/)

I have the following htm form:

```
<head>
   <title>Mashup</title>
   <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head>

//html body    

 <script type="text/javascript">

   $(window).load(function () {

       function AppViewModel() {
           this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
           this.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");
       }

       var model = ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
       alert(model);
   });
```

I've also tried using document ready:

```
   //I've also tried document ready but still not working.

   $(document).ready(function () {
       function AppViewModel() {
           this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
           this.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");
       }

    var model = ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
    alert(model);
});
```

I know ir will be something really stupid.  Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do make two mistakes:

1. ko.applyBindings() does not return the model.

   ```
   // Create the view model
   var model = new AppViewModel();

   // Apply bindings using this model
   ko.applyBindings(model);
   ```
2. In your fiddle, you're trying to use the "value" binding on a `<label>` element. Such elements have no "value" property since you cannot enter anything. You need to use the "text" binding here:

   ```
   <label id="lblFilename" data-bind="text: firstName"></label>
   ```

http://jsfiddle.net/4748N/8/

Answer (score 1):

`ko.applyBindings` doesn't return a model. You pass model to `applyBinding` that will be binded to the html. Modify your code to this:

```
   function AppViewModel() {
       this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
       this.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");
   }

   var model = new AppViewModel();
   ko.applyBindings(model);
   alert(model.firstName());
```

Comment: Thanks - I think you were in first :)

Answer (score 1):

The `ko.applyBindings()` is not returning what you expect. Create the model and then apply bindings to it. Here's an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4748N/7/).

Code:

```
function AppViewModel() {
    this.firstName = "Davy";
    this.lastName = "Cassidy";
}

var model = new AppViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(model);


alert(model.firstName);
```